# changing MainWindow fontsize when using materialdesign - wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Im using MaterialDesignTheme from this page:
http://materialdesigninxaml.net/

My problem is that i can't change the fontsize of MainWindow.
there is a line that should allow me to change it:

```
TextElement.FontSize="72"
```

but nothing changes when i change the value.
I can still change the fontsize of indiviual controls, but that takes me time, i really want to make a universal fontsize for all controls.

and thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use resources and set universal fontsizes that way?

Comment: i did, but still no effect. sorry for my late response